# Encode &#9679; special character in php

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to store the special char ● inside a database.

I'm doing this:

```
htmlentities($text,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')
```

for reasons I don't understand the char ● does not get encoded, it remains in its "normal" (●) form instead of its encoded (`&#9679;`) form, it looks like this character is part of the utf-8 charset, but I need to have it encoded (`&#9679;`) anyway in the db. I cannot use another charset because I need UTF-8.

Why does this happen?

Thanks

EDIT: It's not a discussion about encoding or not encoding chars in the database, I would like to know why that particular char gets completely ignored.

Comment: You mention PHP, but what specific type of database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Why do you need to encode it to store it in the database…?

Comment: deceze asks a great question. Don't worry about encoding things when you store them: store the data raw, and then encode it with `htmlentities()` when you display it in your HTML.

Comment: @all I need to strip those character later and the only safe way to do it is from the encoded form.

Comment: *"otherwise problems will arise"* To be honest, I think you're doing something wrong and are trying to fix it at the wrong end. You can always HTML encode the data later when it's actually necessary to do so. But there's virtually no reason to store garbled (i.e. encoded in any form) data in a database.

Comment: @deceze, I personally prefer to have text encoded in the database and that's exactly what the htmlentities function does. I only have problem with that character, there are tons of solutions to this problem, I still want to know why this happens to learn something new. I haven't asked if I should encode characters, I asked why that specific character doesn't get encoded and nobody apparently knows why..

Comment: Your question is perfectly valid and I'd like to know the answer too. But why in the world do you need to encode it when it goes *into* the database?! There's simply no good reason for it, sorry.

Comment: @deceze I think it's a matter of choice. I personally prefer to have no html at all in the database in order for it to be encoding agnostic. I encountered several problems with encoding especially in the mssql environment where there are propietary encodings, I took the habit to store the html encoded to avoid any sort of problems, it may be not the best practice, but it's the safest way and unless proven othewise I'll keep doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the multi-byte functions to convert your UTF-8 string to US-ASCI while replacing any non-ASCII character by a character reference:

```
mb_substitute_character('entity');
$ascii = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8');
```

Although I don’t see any reason to do this either. Your database won’t interpret any string as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function with a widest set of HTML entities is probably [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding):

```
<?php
// Assuming UTF-8 input:
echo mb_convert_encoding('●', 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

In any case, once you've stored plain text as HTML, it's difficult to get it back to plain text (or re-encode it if specs change). I'd recommend storing stuff as-is.